# Detecting the substring from string of first detecting word

Tags: python, string, substring

I am trying to detect the first character from a string and detect it until the next word appears.

For example: `Str = 'xDxxzacBxsxsZxxs' and Set = 'DBZ' Output should be, output = 'xDxxzacBxsxsZ'`

I am trying below code but not able to detect the words related to Set.

```
def F(S, T):
    for t in T:
        if t not in S: return False
    Start=T[t] // error here, I am trying to get the index
Str = 'xDxxzacBxsxsZxxs'
Set = 'DBZ'
F(Str,Set)
```

Update:

It should detect the word from substring and detect it till the end of finding all possible substring words but only once, for example, `str=xDxxzacBxsxsZxxsDxxB` in this case output should stop on `DxxzacBxsxsZ` because we have find all the possible substring once

Comment: i don't understand your example.

Comment: it should return the first substrings of words Set

Comment: is the word set string in the same order as string in Str? or can it be any order?

Comment: @RishabhKumar any order, like `xBxxDxxxZxxDxxxBxxxAxBxBxxxDxxBxDx` first possible sub strings are `xBxxDxxxZ`

Comment: I updated the question with more explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by a straight-forward logic:

```
def F(S, T):
    for t in T:
        if t not in S: return False
    T = list(T)
    for i in range(len(S)):
        if S[i] in T:
            T.remove(S[i])
            if len(T)==0:break
    print(S[:i+1])
Str = 'xBxxDxxxZxxDxxxBxxxAxBxBxxxDxxBxDx'
Set = 'DBZ'
F(Str,Set)
```

Output:

```
xBxxDxxxZ
```

This is a much shorter solution:

```
def F(S, T):
    return S[:max([S.find(i) for i in T])+1]


Str = 'xBxxDxxxZxxDxxxBxxxAxBxBxxxDxxBxDx'
Set = 'DBZ'
print(F(Str,Set))
```

Output:

```
xBxxDxxxZ
```

Comment: Error: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: @AHF have you done any modification to this code?, cause it runs without any errors on my system.

Comment: No I didn't perform any modification

Comment: You must be having variables in your code with this name `set`

Comment: What if I am interested in starting from first substring and instead of starting from `x` start from `BxxDxxxZ`

Comment: @AHF in my second solution replace the return statement with this: `return S[min([S.find(i) for i in T]):max([S.find(i) for i in T])+1]`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I've understood your question completely, the wording is a bit vague, but if this is what you're trying to do:

Given 2 strings S and T, check that all the characters of T are present in S in *any* order (but can have other characters between them as well) and if they are, return the shortest substring of S from the start till the point where all characters of T are present.

Then this might work:

```py
def F(S, T):
    for i in range(1,len(S)):
        substr = S[:i]
        if all([char in substr for char in T]):
            return substr
    return False
```

Comment: Perfect answer, except it should not detect any word before it detect first string from set

Comment: also can you please explain why we performing this step ? len(S) in for loop

Comment: @AHF , I am checking all the substrings 'x' , 'xD', 'xDx' , 'xDxx', 'xDxxz', etc till the entire string S (same as `S[:len(S)-1]` ) and stopping at the point where all characters in T are present.

Comment: It shouldn't check any letter until it detect first letter from substring

Answer (score 0):

You can return Str when it has gone over each element of Set **once**:

```py
def F(S, T):
    num = 0
    for row in range(len(S)):
        if num >= len(T):
            return S[:row]
        if S[row] == T[num]:
            num += 1

Str = 'xDxxzacBxsxsZxxs'
Set = 'DBZ'

print(F(Str, Set))
```

Comment: It should only detect the first one, like Str = 'xDxxzacBxsxsZxxsDxx' but output should be till only the first detection like `output = 'xDxxzacBxsxsZ`

Comment: It returns `xDxxzacBxsxsZ` given your example.

Comment: Its not working for other scenarios like `xBxxDxxxZxxDxxxBxxxAxBxBxxxDxxBxDx` first possible sub strings are `xBxxDxxxZ`

Answer (score 0):

First of all `Start=T[t]` gives an error because t is `str` not `int`.

---

Also try out this:

```
index=list()
str='xDxxzacBxsxsZxxs'
set='DBZ'
for i in range(len(str)):
    for j in set:
        if j==str[i]:
            index.append(i)
print(str[:max(index)+1])
```

Comment: It should detect the word from substring and detect it till the end of finding all possible substring words but only once, for example, `str=xDxxzacBxsxsZxxsDxxB' in this case output should stop on `xDxxzacBxsxsZ` because we have find all the possible substring once